# Looking for an apocalyptic fantasy book

Tags: story-identification, magic

I think it was a "magic returns" type of story.

There was the revival of an aztec/mayan sorcerer. He and an underling ate a prostitutes heart for power.

There was a woman fighting them, who had been basically a new age pagan but her powers were growing (iirc).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great start. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and and see if you can edit in any more details.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy. Please make sure you've checked out the [tour], read [ask] (and possibly [answer]), as well as the [Story-ID guidelines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info). What language did you read it in? Where were you when you read it? Medium? Etc. I hope you decide to stick around! I'd also recommend that you **[register your account](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/why-register)**, which will give you access to more features of the site, such as voting.

Comment: Sounds a bit like Mercedes Lackey's Burning Water (https://www.amazon.com/Burning-Water-Diana-Tregarde-Investigation-ebook/dp/B00JOOQHH8) - new age witch Diana Tregarde fighting returning Aztec god.  Can't remember if it's got the eating of a prostitutes heart....

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it. It was definitely not a romance novel.